# T-SQL Statements to Grant Access and Create Account

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, t-sql, orchestration

If i have to grant access to Database using `T-SQL` and also verify if user already exist in `SQL` ,
If user don't exist then create account first and then grant access to database.

If user exist, just grant access to database.

I only create users in `SQL`. Not in Windows.

What will be by `T-SQL` Query to achieve above. ?

Comment: Logins are server wide, users are accounts in databases possibly based on logins. [`CREATE LOGIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql), [`CREATE USER FROM LOGIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql), `SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE [type] IN ('S', 'U')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create your login first, and the your user. This code first checks where all your users are assigned to which databases. Afterwards it checks if there is a login created and then it checks if the user exists. It is also set dynamically to you can just enter a DBName.

**Example**

```
---Get information on which users has access to my datase
set nocount on
declare @permission table (
Database_Name sysname,
User_Role_Name sysname
)
declare @dbs table (dbname sysname)
declare @Next sysname
insert into @dbs
select name from sys.databases order by name
select top 1 @Next = dbname from @dbs
while (@@rowcount<>0)
begin
insert into @permission
exec('use [' + @Next + ']
SELECT ''' + @Next + ''', a.name as ''User or Role Name''
FROM [' + @Next + '].sys.database_principals a 
left join [' + @Next + '].sys.database_permissions d on a.principal_id = d.grantee_principal_id

order by a.name, d.class_desc')
delete @dbs where dbname = @Next
select top 1 @Next = dbname from @dbs
end
set nocount off


--Declare my Variables
Declare @DBName VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @IsWindowsUser int = 0
DECLARE @UserName nvarchar(50) = 'hestt4545tt'
DECLARE @PassWord nvarchar(50) = 'hest123123'
DECLARE @LoginExists int
DECLARE @UserExists int

DECLARE @LoginSQL nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @UserSQL nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @MultiDatabase nvarchar(max) ='LegOgSpass,LoadConfiguration'
--SET @DBName = 'LegOgSpass'



DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
select [value] from string_split(@MultiDatabase,',')

OPEN myCursor
FETCH NEXT  FROM myCursor INTO @DBName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 exec('USE '+ @DBName)


IF @IsWindowsUser = 0
BEGIN
/* Users are typically mapped to logins, as OP's question implies, 
so make sure an appropriate login exists. */

SET @LoginExists = (Select count(principal_id) FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = @UserName)

---Check if login exists - else create it
IF @LoginExists = 0
    BEGIN
         /* Syntax for SQL server login.  See BOL for domain logins, etc. */
        SET @LoginSQL = 'USE ' +@DBName + ' CREATE LOGIN '+@UserName +' WITH PASSWORD = '''+@PassWord+'''' 
        PRINT 'Login doesnt exists'
        EXEC (@LoginSQL)
        PRINT 'Therefore i make a new login now'

    SET @LoginExists = (Select count(principal_id) FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = @UserName)
    IF @LoginExists = 1
    PRINT 'Login is now created and exists'
        BEGIN
        SET @UserExists = (SELECT count(principal_id) FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = @UserName)
            IF @UserExists =0 
                PRINT 'User doesnt exists'
                BEGIN
                    SET @UserSQL = 'USE ' +@DBName+ ' CREATE USER ' +@UserName +' FOR LOGIN '+@UserName

                    EXEC (@UserSQL)
                    PRINT 'User is now created'
                END 
        END
    END
ELSE


    BEGIN
    SET @UserExists =  (select COUNT(distinct User_Role_Name) from @permission where User_Role_Name  =@UserName and Database_Name = @DBName)
            IF @UserExists =0 
            BEGIN
            PRINT 'Login already exists - go create user for access to database'
            SET @UserSQL = 'USE ' +@DBName+ ' CREATE USER ' +@UserName +' FOR LOGIN '+@UserName

            EXEC (@UserSQL)
            PRINT 'User is now created'
            END
    END

END
ELSE

BEGIN
SET @LoginExists = (Select count(principal_id) FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = REPLACE(REPLACE(@UserName,'[',''),']',''))

---Check if login exists - else create it
IF @LoginExists = 0
    BEGIN
         /* Syntax for SQL server login.  See BOL for domain logins, etc. */
        SET @LoginSQL = 'USE ' +@DBName + ' CREATE LOGIN '+@UserName +' FROM WINDOWS' 
        PRINT 'Windows Login doesnt exists'
        EXEC (@LoginSQL)
        PRINT 'Therefore i make a new window login now'

    SET @LoginExists = (Select count(principal_id) FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = @UserName)
    IF @LoginExists = 1
    PRINT 'Windows Login is now created and exists'
        BEGIN
        SET @UserExists = (SELECT count(principal_id) FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = @UserName)
            IF @UserExists =0 
                PRINT 'User doesnt exists'
                BEGIN
                    SET @UserSQL = 'USE ' +@DBName+ ' CREATE USER ' +@UserName +' FOR LOGIN '+@UserName

                    EXEC (@UserSQL)
                    PRINT 'User is now created'
                END 
        END
    END
ELSE



    BEGIN
    SET @UserExists =  (select COUNT(distinct User_Role_Name) from @permission where User_Role_Name  =REPLACE(REPLACE(@UserName,'[',''),']','') and Database_Name = @DBName)
            IF @UserExists =0 
            BEGIN
            PRINT 'Window Login already exists - go create user for access to database'
            SET @UserSQL = 'USE ' +@DBName+ ' CREATE USER ' +@UserName +' FOR LOGIN '+@UserName

            EXEC (@UserSQL)
            PRINT 'User is now created'
            END
    END

END
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @DBName
--Ending cursor
END
CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

Comment: I just added a more dynamically script, i hope this i what you are looking for @ManvendraBele

Comment: Thanks this script is nice

Comment: @ManvendraBele your welcome, remember to mark it as correct so others can benefit from it.

Comment: Thank You for all the help plaidDK. just want to know what will be script in case we are using domain account. ?

Comment: @ManvendraBele I have now updated the script. I created a variable called IsWindowsUser. If this is set to 1 it would create windows users. As you see you need to write your user like [DOMAIN\USERNAME]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154514/discussion-between-manvendra-bele-and-plaiddk).

Comment: How do build  a t-sql query to grant access to users on multiple database in multiple instance.

eg:
Instance 1 - Database A
Instance 2 - Database B

How i grant access to both the database to a single windows user.

My query should also check the SQL Instance if the database is present before giving access.

Comment: @ManvendraBele create a new question please :) You can in your new question refer to this topic

Comment: You left the chat so i write it here in my comment. I have now updated the script so you can add to multiple databases. This however requires SQL 2016 since im using STRING_SPLIT function. Otherwise you need to find out how to split it yourself (Create new question) - On that side, now you have the script to loop through multiple databases, so you can do the same for instance. That should be the outer loop.